# Select an object from a List(Of T) based on the T.ResultName.Value in the object

Tags: vb.net, winforms, linq

I have an object (Test) in a list Dim Tests as List(Of Test). Each Test as a List(Of Results). Results is a simple class with several properties, one being the Test Temperature. I am trying to get the Test from the Test list that has a result named Test Temperature that has a value of whatever is in ary(1).

```
    Dim Tests as List(Of Test)  
    'Put tests in the list
    'Do some other stuff
    'Get a specific test from the list      
    Dim aTest As Test = Tests.Where(Function(y) y.Results.Where(Function(z) z.Name = "Test 
    Temperature" And z.Value = ary(1))).FirstOrDefault()
```

I can't find the right way to combine the Wheres so it finds the right value and returns the correct test. I have tried several variations of the above.

```
    Dim aTest As LimsTest = Tests.FirstOrDefault(Function(y) y.Results.Any(Function(z) z.Name = "Test Temperature" AndAlso z.Value = ary(1)))
```

Comment: `Tests` variable has been declared but never initialized...

Comment: The Tests is actually initialized in the constructor. I just typed it here so it would be clear that it is a List(Of T) where T has been defined.

Comment: This did not select the object. I just passed it by. Stepping through the code I can see the Temperature and the value it is being tested against and they are equal. But it completes without selecting the item. I had to use FirstOrDefault() because DefaultIfEmpty() or First() threw an exception. I don't have a default. In fact, I want aTest to be nothing if it doesn't find the item.

Comment: Please, see updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please, read my comment to the question.

```
Dim aTest As Test = Tests
    .FirstOrDefault(Function(y) y.Results
       .Any(Function(z) z.Name = "Test Temperature" AndAlso z.Value = ary(1)))
```

For further details, please see:
[FirstOrDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_FirstOrDefault__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__)
[Any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Any__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__)
[All](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=net-5.0)

Comment: You don't need to call `Where` and `FirstOrDefault`. The latter will filter without the former. Also, while the OP made the same mistake, that `And` ought to be `AndAlso`.

Comment: @MaciejLos - Thank you. I have read those references. But the line of code does not return the object that is clearly seen meeting the requirements when stepping through the code. I would attach a screen shot if I knew how. See my edited code in the original post.

Comment: I don't know why an object is not returned. I've written [.net-fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0OMlvN) for you. It's working fine.